# How to disable part of UISegmentedControl?

Tags: iphone, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

Following is the code for `UISegmentedControl`

```
UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects: [UIImage imageNamed:@"down.png"], [UIImage imageNamed:@"dList.png"], nil]];  

[segmentedControl addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];  
segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 90, 65);  
segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;  
segmentedControl.momentary = YES;  

UIBarButtonItem *segmentBarItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:segmentedControl];  

[segmentedControl release];  

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = segmentBarItem;  

[segmentBarItem release];
```

and

```
- (void)segmentAction:(id)sender{
    if([sender selectedSegmentIndex] == 0)
    {
        button.hidden=NO;
    }
    else
    {
        [self dListMethod ];
    }
}
```

In the if() section I want to disable `selectedSegmentIndex==0` and enable when `button.hidden=YES`

Comment: You don't want the line `if([sender selectedSegmentIndex] == 0)` to execute if `button.hidden = NO`?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

Use `setEnabled:forSegmentAtIndex:` method to enable and disable the segments.

```
[segmentedControl setEnabled:NO forSegmentAtIndex:0];
```

if you want to disable the first segment.

Answer (score 28):

For those who can be interested in the **swift** command:

**Swift 2.3**

```
segmentedControl.setEnabled(false , forSegmentAtIndex: 0);
```

**Swift 3**

```
self.segmentedControl.setEnabled(false, forSegmentAt: 0);
```