# How to hide a segment in segment control?

Tags: objective-c, uisegmentedcontrol

This is like [how to disable part of uisegment control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355968/how-to-disable-part-of-uisegment-control)

Except that rather than disabling it I want to just hide it. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK you can't hide segments. You'll have to remove it if you want it to disappear. Just call

```
- (void)removeSegmentAtIndex:(NSUInteger)segment animated:(BOOL)animated
```

and you can remove the segment you don't want to show. You can add it back with

```
- (void)insertSegmentWithTitle:(NSString *)title atIndex:(NSUInteger)segment animated:(BOOL)animated
```

or

```
- (void)insertSegmentWithImage:(UIImage *)image atIndex:(NSUInteger)segment animated:(BOOL)animated
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a UIView and place it over the segment you want to disappear, provided the UIView would be filled with a color or image (if you use a UIImageView) that would match the view behind the segment control.

Then you could hide it or show it as needed, covering the segment.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with this :

```
[segmentCnt setTitle:@"" forSegmentAtIndex:index];
[segmentCnt setWidth:0.1 forSegmentAtIndex:index];
```

Also, you need to remove text/title of that segment to hide it.